# Fallback authentication if mod_auth_kerb fails

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, kerberos, single-sign-on, rsa

Is there a way for Apache to fall back to a different authentication method if Kerberos authentication (for some reason) fails? The order of the authentication methods should be:

- Kerberos
- Active Directory
- RSA token

The RSA token authentication is used by external parties who do not have AD accounts.

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

My current config is as follows:

```
<Directory "/path/to/directory">
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Please provide credentials to log in"
  KrbAuthoritative off
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthBasicAuthoritative off
  AuthBasicProvider this-sso this-ad this-radius
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

Authentication aliases are below:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias kerberos this-sso>
  KrbAuthRealms THIS.LOCAL
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd off
  KrbDelegateBasic on
  Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/this.keytab.key
  KrbServiceName HTTP
  KrbVerifyKDC off
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap this-ad>
  Include /etc/apache2/.ldapbinddn
  AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://srv1.this.local srv2.this.local:636/OU=DIR,DC=this,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias xradius this-radius>
  AuthXRadiusAddServer "rsasrv1.this.local:1812" "Shared_key_here"
  AuthXRadiusTimeout 7
  AuthXRadiusRetries 2
  AuthXRadiusRejectBlank on
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

Answer (score 1):

The website of the mod_auth_kerb module is somewhat unclear about this, stating at one point that `AuthType` must be set to Kerberos, but also implying that "if your AuthType is Basic" that it will essentially use the username/password pair that `AuthType Basic` provides to check against your Kerberos server.

The other directives you have for Kerberos, specifically `KrbDelegateBasic on`, don't seem to be documented at the sourceforge page for this module, making me wonder which version of this module you're using.

But, putting that aside for the moment, unless the mod_auth_kerb module is somehow able to hand along the values it gets to the next authentication module in the chain in a way that the next module can understand, this likely won't work.

As a test, I'd change `AuthType` to `Basic`, `KrbMethodNegotiate` to `off`, and `KrbMethodK5Passwd` to `on`, and see if that changes the behavior at all.  This would hopefully cause mod_auth_kerb to gather the login data in a way that the other modules can understand, prevent the authentication method from being negotiated, and attempt to gather a username/password rather than a ticket.

The negotiation part is is important, since that's done for each connection, and thus, if the client browser negotiates a method that screws up the next authentication method, it won't ever get past the Kerberos auth.

I will say that I've never configured Kerberos auth on Apache, so this is somewhat of a guess.  I have done LDAP falling back to file-based Basic auth, though, so I know the fall-through mechanism works, in general.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice on those suggestions. Fallback from LDAP to RSA works (they use basic auth). If only there was a way to mix two `AuthType`s...

BTW, I'm using [v5.4 of mod_auth_kerb from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modauthkerb/files/mod_auth_kerb/mod_auth_kerb-5.4/).

Comment: If fallback works between the two providers that both use AuthType Basic, and mod_auth_kerb doesn't support AuthType Basic, you may be out of luck.  However, at least one person has patched the mod_auth_kerb module to do this:  cf http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=74B0045B-2BEE-43E3-8C94-56A3B6608686%40jpl.nasa.gov&forum_name=modauthkerb-help
I'm not sure if this patch made it into the main branch, but that thread does have working configs, so it might be useful to you.